# Intrusion detection system and firewalling

Tags: firewalls

I have a website and hosted some data and MySQL files on it. Is it possible for me to install an intrusion detection system on it, or can IDSs only be installed on my internal network where I have a router?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this really depends on a couple of factors.

Are you using your own server? Have you rented a server? Did you just pay for hosting?

If it's your own server, therefore your network, you can install Snort and start to monitoring the network.

If you rented a server, you can install a host-based IDS, for example OSSEC, and monitor the events that occur in the server itself (not in the network).

Finally, if you just paid for hosting, I guess you have to talk with your provider about what can you install. I have never paid for hosting, but I think they only give you access to your website and some database, so I don't think you could install an IDS if this is your case.

Answer (score 0):

You use the term "IDS" and you have more options with that phrase. A NIDS is a network IDS, which requires network access, as you assume. A HIDS is a host IDS that can be installed on the server itself.

All of ytZ's info is relevant to figuring out if you can install one or the other.